# Rails holding on to DB connections too long, can't run Stored Procedures

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, stored-procedures, rds

I'm experiencing a problem with Rails and my MySQL RDS Instance. I have my rails app connected to it through our database.yml file with a pool of 10 (now 5) connections. The other day another user of the database tried running a stored procedure but it would not execute. It was stuck just hanging around waiting to execute. The user looked at the processes and noticed that our rails user had around 30 idle processes so they killed some of those. The stored procedure kicked off then and ran without issue.

We are on an r3.xlarge instance and had ~100 total processes at the time of problem. This doesn't seem alarmingly high to me and I'm not sure why the procedure wouldn't execute without freeing up some of the processes. I guess my question is, is there a way to tell my rails app to release some of these idle connections after x seconds, or a way to control these connections better? I can write a cron which frees them up, but I'd love to do it the rails/best way.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that you may have hit the maximum connections limit on the MySQL instance. You can run `select @@max_connections` on your MySQL to find out the limit.

I don't know of a way to force Rails to close its allocated db connections. **Each server process may use up to the *pool size* connections** (i.e. 10 or 5 in your case) **to the db for its threads**. The distinction between threads and processes is important: if you for example have multiple workers serving your rails app running as separate processes (e.g. puma can be configured like that), then each of the process may allocate up to 5 or 10 connections. If you use background processes (sidekiq etc.), they also may use up to this amount of connections.

The `ConnectionPool` also provides a [reaper](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/ConnectionPool/Reaper.html) that can be used to free allocated db connections from *dead* threads but unless your app is having some larger troubles, this usually will not help (your threads are more probably *idle* than *dead*).

So, I'd give a general advice to try to estimate the maximum number of connections that all your rails processes might need and if it is near or above the MySQL connection limit, either lower the connection pool size or decrease the number of possibly run Rails processes (workers).

If you need more help, please specify what application server do you use to run your Rails app and how it is configured and the same also for any background job workers.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `reaping_frequency` in your database.yml file:

> reaping_frequency: frequency in seconds to periodically run the Reaper,
>   which attempts to find and recover connections from dead threads,
>   which can occur if a programmer forgets to close a connection at the
>   end of a thread or a thread dies unexpectedly. Regardless of this
>   setting, the Reaper will be invoked before every blocking wait.
>   (Default nil, which means don't schedule the Reaper)

Above documentation from: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/ConnectionPool.html